# Running `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` after host restarts without halting Vagrant, VM enters aborted/error state

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I get this error:

he program 'brew' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
Illegal option -s
Usage: /usr/bin/which [-a] args
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 1: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: �����H: Protocol error
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 2: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: ���H__PAGEZERO__TEXT�M�M: Protocol error
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 3: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: ��/__dof_node__TEXT��/��/__unwind_info__TEXTT�/�TT�/__eh_frame__TEXT0*1@�0*__DATA�M�
                                                    �M�: Protocol error
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 4: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v9.5.0 --silent` to unset it.
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 1: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: �����H: Protocol error
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 2: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: ���H__PAGEZERO__TEXT�M�M: Protocol error
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 3: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: ��/__dof_node__TEXT��/��/__unwind_info__TEXTT�/�TT�/__eh_frame__TEXT0*1@�0*__DATA�M�
                                                    �M�: Protocol error
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: 4: /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/bin/node: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v9.5.0 --silent` to unset it.
-bash: /usr/libexec/java_home: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by checking the Vagrantfile it had an error due to a misplaced line.